# Reuse of a field from a joined table inside a subquery in FROM clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join, correlated-subquery

The following query is not the one I'm using really, but my problem can be replicated in this simpler one. Basically, what I want to do is use or reference a field from a joined table inside a subquery that is in a `FROM` clause like so.

```sql
SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2 - IIF(t3.calcfield is null, 0, t3.calc)
FROM
  (SELECT t2.fieldid, SUM(t2.field3) AS fsum
   FROM t2
   WHERE t2.date > t4.date 
   GROUP BY t2.fieldid) t3
LEFT JOIN
  table4 t4 ON t3.fieldid = t4.fieldid
```

The field that I need to use is `t4.date` to make the date comparison inside the subquery but when I execute the query I get the popup window or prompt to enter a value in `t4.date`.

I just wanted to make that comparison for filtering, so that I can use `fsum` field in the outer `SELECT` statement. I think the query is pretty simple to understand in terms of what I want to achieve.

Even though my query is more complex, I replicated the problem with a simple query like this or even simpler.

I tried replicating it in an AQL sandbox webpage: https://sqltest.net/. Tables generated by the sandbox, and in the upper right corner I selected the Oracle database.

Tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sql_test_a 
( 
    ID         VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    LAST_NAME  VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) 
); 

CREATE TABLE sql_test_b 
( 
    ID         VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) 
); 

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('1', 'John', 'Snow'); 
INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('2', 'Mike', 'Tyson'); 
INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('3', 'Bill', 'Keaton'); 
INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('4', 'Greg', 'Mercury'); 
INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('5', 'Steve', 'Jobs'); 
INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('6', 'Johhny', 'Depp');
```

The SQL code I wrote is the following:

```sql
SELECT T1.ID, TINNER.FIRST_NAME
FROM 
  (SELECT T2.ID FROM sql_test_b T2
   WHERE T1.FIRST_NAME LIKE 'greg') TINNER
INNER JOIN
  sql_test_a T1 ON t1.ID = TINNER.ID;
```

I practically get the same error or problem that consists in that the `T1` fields did not exist for the inner subquery or `TINNER` table.

I'm using Microsoft Access 2003. (simply cause I had it previously).

Comment: First query has syntax issues as subquery is missing `FROM` and `t1` is not defined. But IIUC, you will need to inner join `t4` again in subquery. Or to use your example, join `sql_test_a` a second time in subquery.

Comment: @Parfait I thought you could use outer queries fields from inner or subqueries.
I just am trying to do a query as compact as possible reusing tables in the whole query.

Comment: You can if your subquery was a correlated one inside a `SELECT` clause, not in `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses where these subqueries are also known as derived tables.

Comment: @Parfait I see...
I guess in subqueries inside WHERE or having clauses I cannot either, right?

Comment: Depends on how you are using it in those clauses. You can with `IN` and `EXISTS` and maybe `=` on aggregates.

Comment: Giving code that doesn't mean anything does not communictate what you wish it meant. PS When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. PS Learn the order that a SQL query is conceptually evaluated in. That includes learning the scope of names. PS Presumably you are thinking of semantics like SQL Server CROSS/OUTER APPLY & SQL LATERAL.

Comment: @philipxy I'll check those, I think they are not in access though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall SQL's logical order of operations that differ from its lexical order (i.e., order in how it is written). Usually the first step in query processing is the `FROM` clause, then `JOIN`, `ON`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, etc. and usually ending with `ORDER BY` and `SELECT` (ironically one of the last clauses processed though written first).

Technically, your queries do not involve correlated subqueries since there are no inner or outer levels. Specifically, the derived table `t3` and base table `t4` are at the *same* level. The query engine evaluates `t3` in isolation by itself during `FROM` clause step. Then, it evaluates `JOIN` table, `t4`, in isolation by itself and finally applies the matching `ON` logic.

Because `t4` is not defined in the universe of `t3`, MS Access via GUI prompts for that parameter value (where MS Access via ODBC will raise an error). To resolve you have to include all necessary data sources in each table scope:

```sql
SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2 - IIF(t3.calcfield IS NULL, 0, t3.calc) As Diff
FROM
  (SELECT t2.fieldid, SUM(t2.field3) AS fsum
   FROM t2
   INNER JOIN table4 sub_t4
     ON t2.fieldid = sub_t4.fieldid
   WHERE t2.date > sub_t4.date 
   GROUP BY t2.fieldid
  ) t3
LEFT JOIN table4 t4 
  ON t3.fieldid = t4.fieldid
```

---

Often, too, using layered queries is beneficial in Access and can help with final, compact queries:

**`t3` query** *(save below as a query object)*

```sql
SELECT t2.fieldid, SUM(t2.field3) AS fsum
FROM t2
INNER JOIN table4 sub_t4
   ON t2.fieldid = sub_t4.fieldid
WHERE t2.date > sub_t4.date 
GROUP BY t2.fieldid
```

**Final query** *(join saved query)*

```sql
SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2 - IIF(t3.calcfield IS NULL, 0, t3.calc) As Diff
FROM my_saved_query t3
LEFT JOIN table4 t4 
   ON t3.fieldid = t4.fieldid
```

Comment: I wasn't sure how good of a practice was creating and reusing queries in other quries. It surely eases the job a lot and I see it makes queries more compact.
Anyway, I managed to write the query I wanted just using joins which I thought was not possible.
Thanks.